# Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: send_appdata.product_id_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using a custom user model and when i am trying to reference it in other model i am getting an error.

```
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: send_appdata.product_id_id
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
AppOnboarding = get_user_model()
# get data from json
@api_view(['POST'])
def index(request):
    product_id = AppOnboarding.objects.get(pk=request.data['product_id'])

    product_name = request.data['product_name']
    product_url = request.data['product_url']
    subject = request.data['subject']
    body = request.data['body']
    recipient_list = request.data['recipient_list']
    sender_mail = request.data['sender_mail']
    email_type = request.data['email_type']
    broadcast_mail = request.data['broadcast_mail']
    email_status = status.HTTP_200_OK
    location = request.data['location']
    # make an object of AppData
    app_data = AppData(product_id=product_id, product_name=product_name, product_url=product_url,
                       subject=subject, body=body, recipient_list=recipient_list, sender_mail=sender_mail, email_type=email_type, broadcast_mail=broadcast_mail, email_status=email_status, location=location)
    # save it to DB
    app_data.save()
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

AppOnboarding = get_user_model()


class AppData(models.Model):
    # app_data_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(AppOnboarding, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_url = models.URLField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    recipient_list = models.TextField()
    sender_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    email_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    broadcast_mail = models.BooleanField()
    email_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

AppOnboarding is a custom user model in a different app.

I explored the similar questions but could not resolve the issue.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the full traceback and also the part of code where the error is complaining about.

Comment: Exception Location: C:\Users\prpr9003\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\nrn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383

Answer (score 0):

Have added this foreign key `product_id` recently (after the rest of model fields)?
If yes, you need to make it nullable (null=True) and run `makemigrations` then `migrate`

Comment: No, it was there from the beginning, btw I made it nullable but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, when I manually checked using python shell, Apponboarding.objects.get(id=1) was returning Does not exits but  Apponboarding.objects.get(id=2) and others it was returning email address instead of id. It is still not clear how the id started from 2 instead of 1 (since it is auto field) and why email is getting returned instead of id.

Comment: But after adding     product_user = AppOnboarding.objects.get(id=request.data['product_id'])
    product_id = product_user.id ,i am getting ,Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "9": "AppData.product_id" must be a "AppOnboarding" instance.